# Sensu plugin's tune to send perf data to Graphite via amqp

Tags: performance, plugins, graphite, tweak, sensu

I'm trying to tweak a perf-data+value-check plugin (I mean, one that checks some warning-critical values AND collects perf-data) to send this perf-data to Graphite via amqp. This was done in metrics plugin (metric_vmstat.rb) but I still cannot see an easy example of lines to add to any plugin to make it suitable.
Can you recommend some?
Thanks!!

Comment: What exactly would be 'suitable' for you? Can you localize your problem a little more? Seems like you're looking for a ruby library to send data via amqp.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Example: http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Linux/check_linux_stats/details. This plugin shoots this: "LOAD AVERAGE OK : 0.37,0.22,0.23 |load1=0.37;10;20;0 load5=0.22;8;18;0 load15=0.23;5;15;0. So, how can I get this graphed in graphite?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metrics_vmstat.rb plugin inherits a lot of its functionality from `Sensu::Plugin::Metric::CLI::Graphite`. You might try having your plugin inherit from the same class.

Alternatively, since Sensu and Graphite both use amqp, you can configure sensu-server to route the metrics for you. Check out method 2 in Joe Miller's blog post (http://joemiller.me/2012/02/02/sensu-and-graphite/), that should help get you started.

Comment: Thanks @beerops. The issue here is that the check_linux_stats.pl is written in perl, so this class won't apply right? or won't be defined the same way than ruby.
Additionally, I've the circuit (sensu-redis-graphite) running and working with other checks and metrics using amqp. But this particular check is not working.